# Checking if a sessions is empty, unsetting it, and then sending $_POST data onclick

Tags: javascript, php, session

I have two possible sets of information to export to another PHP page whenever i click a button.
One of them is a session. It's something like this:

```
$_SESSION['excel_name']['Main_'] = "Main_".date("y_m_d_Hi");
$_SESSION['excel_array']['Main_']['Plan1'] = array();
```

The post data sends the same information, but doesn't save it in a session to prevent conflict between too many sessions. So what i want to try, is to check if there is a session set. If there is, i'll unset it, and send the $_POST data. When there isn't, i'll set one. I have tried doing this:

```
session_start();
if(isset($_SESSION) && !empty($_SESSION)) {
    unset($_SESSION['Main_']);
    unset($_SESSION['Plan1']);
    unset($_SESSION['excel_array']);
    $_POST['excel_name']['Main_'] = "Main_".date("y_m_d_Hi");
    $_POST['excel_array']['Main_']['Plan1'] = array();
} else {
    $_SESSION['excel_name']['Main_'] = "Main_".date("y_m_d_Hi");
    $_SESSION['excel_array']['Main_']['Plan1'] = array();
}
```

The logic might seem a little weird for some of you, but i'm almost certain it would work... But. I wanted to do this in a button. Reason being, whenever i click the button, I export the information to the next PHP page. I want to check for these conditions before sending the information, not in the moment i load the page.

Is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is several way to do it, but before reading my answer, please note that javascript verification can be edited and exploited maliciously.

You could do an AJAX request to a php page that would implement your logic and return a code 200 or 401. Then you can act before the next page loads.

Comment: How bad would be the security issue be? Also, is AJAX the only other option? If so, can you show me an example of how to do it?

Comment: Well, in all cases you will need to double-check on the destination page that the rules have been respected, otherwise the user can contourn the verification. So how bad? Well, it depends if you need it to be 100% accurate or if you don't care if people bypass this step.

To check a PHP session, you need to execute some PHP code, so I see only AJAX to do it efficiently, but you might get other creative answers.

Comment: You can also use COOKIES which are also available on the client-side (but also editable). The logic behind this question has been asked several time, see [this google search](https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=site:stackoverflow.com+check+php+session+from+javascript)